# How to join same table twice without duplicate rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables in my database:

- Events: `event_id`, `event_time`, and `event_name`. Each row represents an event that occurred at a specific time.
- TSeries: `data_time`, and `data`. Each row represents a record that was saved one, two, three, or four minute(s) after an event.

I would like to output a table with 6 columns: `event_id`, `event_time`, `data_time1`, `data1`, `data_time2`, and `data2` where `data_time1` and `data1` are for the first 2 minutes after the event (`+0`, `+1`) while `data_time2` and `data2` are for the next 2 minutes (`+3`, `+4`).

My query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM events
LEFT JOIN tseries ts1 
ON ts1.data_time >= (events.event_time) AND ts1.data_time <= (events.event_time + time '00:01:00')
LEFT JOIN tseries ts2 
ON ts2.data_time >= (events.event_time + time '00:02:00') AND ts2.data_time <= (events.event_time + time '00:03:00')
ORDER BY events.event_id
;
```

This query produces this result (I included only the time fields):

```
event_time data_time1 data_time2
     x        x+0        x+2
     x        x+0        x+3
     x        x+1        x+2
     x        x+1        x+3
```

And I would prefer something like this instead:

```
event_time data_time1 data_time2
     x        x+0        x+2
     x        x+1        x+3
```

or

```
event_time data_time1 data_time2
     x        x+0        null
     x        x+1        null
     x        null       x+2
     x        null       x+3
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why are you joining twice? Couldn't you just do the join once when put the rest in the WHERE clause?

Comment: can you add sample data for tables .

Comment: "twice + WHERE" - I don't understand how you think, but I am a beginner. Didn't work for me. Thanks the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation . . . assuming you want only one row per event:

```
SELECT e.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ts.data_time >= e.event_time AND ts1.data_time <= e.event_time + time '00:01:00' THEN ts.data END) as data_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ts.data_time >= e.event_time + time '00:02:00' AND ts2.data_time <= e.event_time + time '00:03:00' THEN ts.data END) as data_2
FROM events e LEFT JOIN
     tseries ts
     ON (ts.data_time >= e.event_time AND ts1.data_time <= e.event_time + time '00:01:00') OR
        (ts.data_time >= e.event_time + time '00:02:00' AND ts2.data_time <= e.event_time + time '00:03:00')
GROUP BY e.event_id
ORDER BY e.event_id;
```

However, this doesn't work for multiple matches in each time period.

For multiple rows, one method is to enumerate the values for each event and each time period.  Then, you can use that sequence number for matching.  The following uses a `FULL JOIN` in case the two lists have different lengths:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ts1.event_id, ts2.event_id) as event_id,
       ts1.data, ts2.data
FROM (SELECT e.event_id, ts1.data,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.event_id ORDER BY ts1.event_time) as seqnum
      FROM events e JOIN
           tseries ts1 
           ON ts1.data_time >= e.event_time AND
              ts1.data_time <= e.event_time + time '00:01:00'
     ) ts1 FULL JOIN
     (SELECT e.event_id, ts1.data,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.event_id ORDER BY ts1.event_time) as seqnum
      FROM events e JOIN
           tseries ts2
           ON ts1.data_time >= e.event_time + time '00:02:00' AND 
              ts1.data_time <= e.event_time + time '00:03:00'
     ) ts2
     ON ts1.event_id = ts2.event_id AND ts1.seqnum = ts2.seqnum
ORDER BY event_id;
```

Note:  If you want the other fields from `event` then you can use:

```
SELECT e.*, 
       ts1.data, ts2.data
FROM events e LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT e.event_id, ts1.data,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.event_id ORDER BY ts1.event_time) as seqnum
      FROM events e JOIN
           tseries ts1 
           ON ts1.data_time >= e.event_time AND
              ts1.data_time <= e.event_time + time '00:01:00'
     ) ts1
     ON ts1.event_id = e.event_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT e.event_id, ts1.data,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.event_id ORDER BY ts1.event_time) as seqnum
      FROM events e JOIN
           tseries ts2
           ON ts1.data_time >= e.event_time + time '00:02:00' AND 
              ts1.data_time <= e.event_time + time '00:03:00'
     ) ts2
     ON e.event_id = ts2.event_id AND ts1.seqnum = ts2.seqnum
ORDER BY e.event_id;
```

Comment: The first one fits my needs with small modifications, but I will try the other two as well. Super :) Thanks! (I didn't met coalesce and partition before)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT distinct
*
FROM events
LEFT JOIN tseries ts1 
ON ts1.data_time >= (events.event_time) AND ts1.data_time <= (events.event_time + time '00:01:00')
LEFT JOIN tseries ts2 
ON ts2.data_time >= (events.event_time + time '00:02:00') AND ts2.data_time <= (events.event_time + time '00:03:00')
ORDER BY events.event_id;
```

Comment: Made the query very long, or infinite? don't know, I didn' wait the end. But thanks for the tip.